# Multiple vhosts on multiple IP addresses

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.2, virtualhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple vhosts on multiple IP addresses](https://serverfault.com/questions/345947/multiple-vhosts-on-multiple-ip-addresses)

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, I have two IP addresses assigned to my VPS (Linode).

I have followed their guide to enable static addresses (can be found here: http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Configure_Static_IPs)

The current situation is that I have 3 websites on that Linode and I want to set them up so site1 and site2 will use IP1 and site3 will use IP3

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com**

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin info@site1.com
  ServerName  site1.com
  ServerAlias www.site1.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/site1/public_html


  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/site1/public_html/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/site1/public_html/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.com**

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin info@site2.com
  ServerName  site2.com
  ServerAlias www.site2.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/site2/public_html


  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/site2/public_html/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/site2/public_html/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/site3.com**

```
<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin info@site3.com
  ServerName  site3.com
  ServerAlias www.site3.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/site3/public_html


  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/site3/public_html/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/site3/public_html/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**Relevant excerpt from ports.conf:**

```
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80
NameVirtualHost 2.2.2.2:80
Listen 1.1.1.1:80
Listen 2.2.2.2:80
```

Problem is, I'm getting the content of site1 on all three sites. I have no idea why this is happening. Can you please assist?

Note: I have ran a2ensite for all 3 websites, no errors/warnings appear when i start the apache2 service.

Comment: Are you able to run `/etc/init.d/apache2 virtualhosts`? That's the command on Gentoo, I'm not sure if it would work on Ubuntu as well but it's worth a shot. It should print out the entire vhost configuration as parsed from the config files, which will let you check directly whether your configurations are being parsed correctly.

Comment: What is the contents of the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ directory?

Comment: I think need clarity on following matters to get proper answer. 1. How configuration folder is setup in main httpd.conf file. Like whether it is *.conf or just *. 2. Where is this port.conf file located.

Comment: This all looks correct. Did you remember to remove the default configuration files in sites-enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your configuration is as you've put above, that's perfect. Make sure you have enabled all the sites you've put in to sites-available though, for example `a2ensite site3.com`. What that command does is create a symlink from the file in sites-available to sites-enabled. Apache by default on Ubuntu is configured to parse anything in sites-enabled but nothing from sites-available; sites-available is just a repository.

Also make sure you're not using *:80 anywhere in your VirtualHost directives.

Failing all of that, run `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` and see what it says your active VirtualHosts are. Post the output here.